# javascript variable initialization using || and {}

Tags: javascript

Could you explain the below one?

```
var lib = lib || {};
```

When do we need to do it? I don't know why `lib` is used again.

Answer (score 2):

if variable `lib` has `falsy` (`null`, `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `''`, `NaN`) value then assign empty (`{}`) object. You also can rewrite your example like this

```
var lib;

if (!lib) {
   lib = {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this statement is to make sure `lib` is a truthy value, and alternatively an empty object.

It's used in many function initialization code where the parameter might not be passed by the caller.

One must pay attention though, `lib` might be `true`, and will remain `true` after this statement, instead of being replaced by an empty object.

Comment: And in EcmaScript 6 you have [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: @Ziki - that's not enough -> `function f(lib = {}) { lib.prop = 1; }; f(null);` will throw an exception.

Comment: if he pass a string or anything else also will not work, in that case he will need to check in all the examples the typeof the variable. but can be solved with policies and jsdocs in IDEs

Comment: @Ziki - `var s = 'abc'; s.prop = 5;` won't set a property, but won't throw an exception either - that's bad, but not terrible. The note in the answer regarding attention to truthy values was meant exactly for these cases.

Comment: You're right, but it's only in null and variables that are not defined(as far as i know)..

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has the following falsy values

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (not a number)

Now if you have for example something like:

```
var foo = function(lib){
    lib = lib || {};
    console.log(lib);
}
```

Calling foo without parameters (causing lib to be undefined) or with one of the above listed one will print lib as an object (as the {} is a truthy value).

Answer (score 0):

if `lib` variable is initialited - `var lib = lib;`, if not - `var lib = {};` `{}` - is an empty object.

Comment: You mean if *lib* has a non–falsey value. All variables are initialised with *undefined* when declared.

Answer (score 0):

If lib is set and not null, false, undefined... Then the new content is whatever lib is before. But if that is not the case, lib will become an empty object.